# Can't connect to another queue with the same Connection Factory

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, activemq-artemis

While running ActiveMQ Artemis locally, I can use the same `ConnectionFactory` to connect in two different queues.
When I try to connect to my client's ActiveMQ I can keep only one consumer active at a time. For the other ones I keep getting:

```
Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'QUEUE_NAME' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=27, maxAttempts=unlimited}. 
Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is 
ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
```

Checking with my client, he told me that on Artemis log he justs sees a bunch of

```
2019-02-06 16:44:44,725 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred.
2019-02-06 16:44:54,595 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred.
2019-02-06 16:45:04,670 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred.
2019-02-06 16:45:54,595 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred.
2019-02-06 16:46:04,655 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred.
```

Now if I create differente `ConnectionFactory`s for each queue, with the exact same parameters, I can connect to them at the same time.

I'm using basically `spring-boot-artemis` (much like [this](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-integration/jms-listener-annotation.html) tutorial) but I don't believe this is something about my code but about ActiveMQ (since it works with my ActiveMQ Artemis locally).

As far as I know, my client did not made any configuration on his ActiveMQ Artemis. It is just the default installation. His ActiveMQ is being used by other applications, which I'm suspecting may cause some kind of starvation on the connection factories...? Any ideas on how to debug or find out about this?

Thanks!

**Edit**

I got the `broker.xml` and removed all my clients data to post here. The queue I'm connecting to is under the `NAME3.#` match rule in the `security-settings` rules and I connect to it using the `my_user` user:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<configuration
  xmlns="urn:activemq"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
  <core
    xmlns="urn:activemq:core"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
    <name>DEV</name>
    <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
    <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
           ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
           MAPPED: mmap files
           NIO: Plain Java Files
       -->
    <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
    <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
    <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
    <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
    <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
    <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
    <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
    <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
    <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
    <jmx-management-enabled>true</jmx-management-enabled>
    <async-connection-execution-enabled>false</async-connection-execution-enabled>
    <!--
       This value was determined through a calculation.
       Your system could perform 3.85 writes per millisecond
       on the current journal configuration.
       That translates as a sync write every 260000 nanoseconds.

       Note: If you specify 0 the system will perform writes directly to the disk.
             We recommend this to be 0 if you are using journalType=MAPPED and ournal-datasync=false.
      -->
    <journal-buffer-timeout>260000</journal-buffer-timeout>
    <journal-buffer-size>1000000</journal-buffer-size>
    <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
       -->
    <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
    <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
         <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->
    <!--
        Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network
         <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->
    <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
    <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->
    <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs
           it should accept IPV6

           Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this is meant to validate if your network is valid.
                    Using IPs that could eventually disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose.
                    You can use a list of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue running -->
    <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->
    <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
    <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->
    <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
    <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->
    <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
    <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
    <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
           that won't support flow control. -->
    <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>
    <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
    <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
    <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
    <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
    <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
    <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit.
           This is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory

            The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size.
            You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your needs.

            <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size>

      -->
    <acceptors>
      <!-- useEpoll means: it will use Netty epoll if you are on a system (Linux) that supports it -->
      <!-- amqpCredits: The number of credits sent to AMQP producers -->
      <!-- amqpLowCredits: The server will send the # credits specified at amqpCredits at this low mark -->
      <!-- Note: If an acceptor needs to be compatible with HornetQ and/or Artemis 1.x clients add
                    "anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic." to the acceptor url.
                    See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1644 for more information. -->
      <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
      <acceptor name="openwire">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;connectionTtl=60000;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;needClientAuth=true;sslEnabled=false;anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.</acceptor>
      <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
      <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpMinCredits=300</acceptor>
      <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
      <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;connectionTtl=60000;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;needClientAuth=true;sslEnabled=false;anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.</acceptor>
      <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
      <!--acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor-->
      <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
      <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true;needClientAuth=true</acceptor>
      <!-- Netty Acceptor -->
      <acceptor name="netty">tcp://localhost:61617?needClientAuth=true;protocols=OPENWIRE,CORE,AMQP,JMS;connectionTtl=60000;;anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.</acceptor>
    </acceptors>
    <connectors>
      <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
      <connector name="itot-remote-connector">tcp://ip.ip.ip.ip:61616</connector>
    </connectors>
    <ha-policy>
      <replication>
        <colocated/>
      </replication>
    </ha-policy>
    <!-- Clustering configuration -->
    <broadcast-groups>
      <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
        <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <broadcast-period>10000</broadcast-period>
        <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
      </broadcast-group>
    </broadcast-groups>
    <discovery-groups>
      <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
        <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
      </discovery-group>
    </discovery-groups>
    <cluster-connections>
      <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
        <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
        <retry-interval>10000</retry-interval>
        <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
        <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>1</max-hops>
        <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
      </cluster-connection>
    </cluster-connections>
    <security-settings>
      <security-setting match="#">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="admin,amq,guest"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="admin,amq,guest,read"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work-->
        <permission type="manage" roles="admin,amq,read"/>
      </security-setting>
      <security-setting match="NAME1.#">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="admin,amq,guest,vinspec"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="admin,amq,guest,read,vinspec"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="admin,amq,vinspec"/>
        <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work-->
        <permission type="manage" roles="admin,amq,read"/>
      </security-setting>
      <security-setting match="NAME2.#">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="admin,amq,guest,other_user,another_user,my_user"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="admin,amq,guest,read,other_user,another_user,my_user"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="admin,amq,other_user,my_user"/>
        <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work-->
        <permission type="manage" roles="admin,amq,read"/>
      </security-setting>
      <security-setting match="NAME3.#">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="admin,amq,guest,other_user,my_user"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="admin,amq,guest,read,other_user,my_user"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="admin,amq,other_user,my_user"/>
        <permission type="manage" roles="admin,amq,read"/>
      </security-setting>
      <security-setting match="NAME4.#">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="admin,amq,guest,other_user,another_user"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="admin,amq,guest,read,other_user,another_user"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="admin,amq,other_user"/>
        <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work-->
        <permission type="manage" roles="admin,amq,read"/>
      </security-setting>
      <security-setting match="NAME5">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="admin,amq,guest,another_user"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="admin,amq,guest,read,another_user"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="admin,amq,another_user"/>
        <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work-->
        <permission type="manage" roles="admin,amq,read"/>
      </security-setting>
      <security-setting match="NAME6">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="admin,amq,guest"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="admin,amq,guest,read"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work-->
        <permission type="manage" roles="admin,amq,read"/>
      </security-setting>
      <security-setting match="NAME7.#">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="admin,amq,guest"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="admin,amq,guest,read"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work-->
        <permission type="manage" roles="admin,amq,read"/>
      </security-setting>
      <security-setting match="NAME8">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="admin,amq,guest"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="admin,amq,guest,read"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work-->
        <permission type="manage" roles="admin,amq,read"/>
      </security-setting>
      <security-setting match="NAME9.#">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="admin,amq"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="admin,amq,guest,my_user"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="admin,amq,guest,read,my_user"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="admin,amq,my_user"/>
        <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work-->
        <permission type="manage" roles="admin,amq,read"/>
      </security-setting>
    </security-settings>
    <address-settings>
      <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
      <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
        <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
        <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
        <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
        <default-address-routing-type>ANYCAST</default-address-routing-type>
      </address-setting>
      <!--default for catch all-->
      <address-setting match="#">
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
        <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
        <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
        <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
        <default-address-routing-type>ANYCAST</default-address-routing-type>
      </address-setting>
    </address-settings>
    <addresses>
      <address name="DLQ">
        <anycast>
          <queue name="DLQ" />
        </anycast>
      </address>
      <address name="ExpiryQueue">
        <anycast>
          <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
        </anycast>
      </address>
    </addresses>
    <!-- Uncomment the following if you want to use the Standard LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin pluging to log in events -->
    <broker-plugins>
      <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
        <property key="LOG_ALL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
        <property key="LOG_CONNECTION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
        <property key="LOG_SESSION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
        <property key="LOG_CONSUMER_EVENTS" value="true"/>
        <property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
        <property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
        <property key="LOG_INTERNAL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
      </broker-plugin>
    </broker-plugins>
  </core>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The `AMQ224088` handshake timeout error indicates that something on the network is connecting to the ActiveMQ Artemis broker, but it's not completing any protocol handshake. This is commonly seen with, for example, load balancers that do a health check by creating a socket connection without sending any real data just to see if the port is open on the target machine. It may have nothing at all to do with your issue. According to the log the message is occurring every 60 seconds which indicates to me it's caused a health ping of some kind and not your application.

Comment: Can you provide the broker.xml from the broker to which you can't connect?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Justin. Will ask my client for more logs and the broker.xml.

Comment: @JustinBertram I was able to get the broker.xml. Do you see anything strange there? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see anything that provides any clue of what may be happening.